# Get a member of object with square

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, object

```
public function get_Gol($idComp, $idSq){
    global $wpdb;
    $row = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(F_id_gioc_Gol) FROM `ASD_Partite` p
        LEFT JOIN ASD_CALCIO_Partite_Gol cpg ON p.id = cpg.F_id_dett_partita
        WHERE p.F_id_comp = %d AND (p.F_id_sq1 = %d OR p.F_id_sq2 = %d) AND F_id_gioc_Gol = %d", $idComp, $idSq, $idSq, $this->idGioc));
    foreach ($row as $key => $v){

        return $v->count(F_id_gioc_Gol);
    }
```

The problem is that `$v->count(F_id_gioc_Gol);` don't work. how can i access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT count(F_id_gioc_Gol) as gioc_count  ...
```

...

```
return $v->gioc_count;
```

Naming the variable should ease accessing it. You could also use debugger or var_dump to see how to access the fetched count without naming it.